# Questions about feature vector of a tweet in a Twitter Sentiment Analysis Task.

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

https://aclanthology.info/pdf/S/S17/S17-2132.pdf

In this paper that describes one of the systems used in the shared task of SemEval2017, it explains how an SVM Classifier was implemented for a twitter sentiment analysis task.

I am trying to imitate this system, but there are some parts that are not understandable as a beginner.

- It lists bunch of features that describe a single tweet. To implement a feature vector X (where a single row represents a single tweet and the column contains all values of the features listed in the paper) am I supposed to compute vectors for each features and concatenate it at the end?
- One of the features is the Tf-Idf vectorizer. As far as I know, Tf-Idf gives us the weight of the word per document. But in this case, what would be the document? Wouldn't using Tf-idf as one of the features cause the final X to have rows with different numbers of columns? I just want to know how Tf-idf would work here as one of the feature vectors.
- What does the 2.8 Topic and Hashtag feature indicate? I don't quite what kind of value it is describing.

Any kind of advice would be great! Please help!